# Selenium: click() is not working when I print(), and calling error when I comment out print()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying using selenium to automate inputting of student comments into D2L. I am running into a problem that D2L has 2 instances of each element on the same page.

```
    GFD = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='d2l-imagelink'][starts- 
    with(@id,'ICN_Feedback_')][contains(@title,'Enter comments for FIRSTNAME
    LASTNAME in a new window')]")
    print(GFD) 
    GFD.click()
```

`print()` returns:

```
   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
  (session="729913326ada06df2b665cb77e224755", element="0.5122921302415122-1"
```

but the `GFD.click()` wont work. 
To make matters more confusing for me, if i comment out the `print()`, i get an error from the `GFD.click()`

```
 Message: unknown error: Element <a class="d2l-imagelink" 
id="ICN_Feedback_3400653_125630" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return 
false;" title="Enter comments for FIRSTNAME LASTNAME in a new window" aria- 
label="Enter comments for FIRSTNAME LASTNAME in a new window" 
role="button">...</a> is not clickable at point (894, 858). Other element 
would receive the click: <div class="d2l-floating-buttons-inner-container 
style-scope d2l-floating-buttons" style="left: 7.23438px; width: 867.531px;">...</div>
 (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 
 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I know that D2L has put 2 instances of the same link ID on the page (probably just to spite me). Is it possible to `click()` the first instance of this link using find_elements some how?

Comment: What if you found element***s*** by x path, then did `GFD[0].click()`?

Comment: I  end up with error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the error message is very indicative of the problem:

> is not clickable at point (894, 858). Other element 
>   would receive the click:

The object that you are trying to click on sounds like it's covered by another element a div. That sometimes happens even unintentionally. A css or HTML error might cause a transparent div to overlay any other DOM element. The simplest solution is to hide the offending DIV.

```
GFD = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='d2l-imagelink'][starts- 
    with(@id,'ICN_Feedback_')][contains(@title,'Enter comments for FIRSTNAME
    LASTNAME in a new window')]")
```

Secondly you do not need this elaborate xpath query. Always use [find_element_by_id](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id) when you have an ID available. And also note that according to python naming conventions GFD should be gfd.

```
gfd = driver.find_element_by_id("ICN_Feedback_3400653_125630")
```

And finally.

> To make matters more confusing for me

Are you quite sure, in your xpath code, you are not using the full id in the query. You are using only a part of it. And anyway, as i already mentioned, you don't need xpath here.

Comment: I was using find_element_by_id("ICN_Feedback_3400653_125630", but i kept getting errors. So I was bashing though possible solutions. I will try what you posted. and get back

Comment: Sometimes you need to wait for an element to be clickable as well

Comment: I have tried the time.sleep(10) thing, that was not the case. I will look into hiding the DIV

Answer (score 0):

This error is because another element is overlaying your desired element, the overlay can be short-lived or it could be permanant, If it's short lived, you need to wait for the invisibility of the overlaying element, write this code before you click your desired element

So write this code for the overlay to disappear

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='d2l-floating-buttons-inner-container style-scope d2l-floating-buttons']")));
```

And then you write your code to click that element, when id is there, you don't have to go for xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_id("ICN_Feedback_3400653_125630").click()
```

Now it will work

NOTE: `ElementToBeClickable` wouldn't wait in this place because it's assuming element is clickable when element is enabled but element is enabled even when it's overlay-ed by another element.

If the overlay is not short-lived and it's permanant, then use the JavaScript click on the desired element, it would work for you.